# Alternate image position within a div with display:table each time div appears - jquery, php, wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, css, wordpress

Sorry for the vague question title, but I don't exactly know how to explain my problem in one line.

Basically, what I'm trying to create is a page on wordpress that contains a loop of user testimonials. Each testimonial is within it's own div. I've gotten that no problem with this HTML and PHP:

```
<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'testimonials', 'orderby' => 'date', 'order' => 'DESC') ); ?>

    <?php while( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
       <div class="testimonialBox">

          <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>

          <div class="testimonialContent">
             <?php the_content(); ?>
          </div>
        </div>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Obviously the_post_thumbnail is an image, and the_content is text. I wanted to center the text vertically within the div, so I added display:table to .testimonialBox, and display:table-cell vertical-align:middle to .testimonialContent. This works as well, here is all my CSS:

```
.testimonialBox {
width: 100%;
padding: 10px;
margin: 50px 0;
border: 2px solid #c90;
box-shadow: -5px 5px 20px #888888;
min-height: 300px;
display: table; 
}
.testimonialContent {
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

However, I want the testimonials to alternate between one having an image on the left/text on the right, and the next one has image on the right/text on the left, then back again. Can I do this with jQuery?

*PS - using float:left or float:right on the img doesn't work since the div has a display:table. The elements appear in the order they are written in the HTML.*

Comment: Why don't you simply add an extra class to each testimonial div that alternates for odd/even item e.g. odd class image left/text right, even class image right/text left?

Comment: @ManosForsaken I don't think I can do that since in order to move the image to the right side, I need to actually change the HTML, not add a different class (since I am using display:table). Correct me if I'm wrong? What CSS could I use to do that? Thanks

Comment: Well you dynamically add the HTML so you could place it accordingly using an if statement. That's of course if you don't want to bother with the extra javascript part. I would prefer that to be honest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**CSS can handle this.**

you can select boxes via `:nth-child(x)` and then ,

with `display : table;` you can use `direction` :

for older browsers

- instead `nth-child` ,  in your loop add a class to the box.
- for the `initial` value, use `rtl/ltr`

```css
/* alternate direction */
.testimonialBox:nth-child(even) {
  direction:rtl;
}
.testimonialBox:nth-child(even) .testimonialContent{
  direction:initial;
}
/* end alternate */
.testimonialBox {
width: 100%;
padding: 10px;
margin: 50px 0;
border: 2px solid #c90;
box-shadow: -5px 5px 20px #888888;
min-height: 300px;
display: table; 
}
.testimonialContent {
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="testimonialBox">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/100" />
  <div class="testimonialContent">
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
      Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus
      lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor,
      facilisis luctus, metus</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="testimonialBox">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/100" />
  <div class="testimonialContent">
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
      Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus
      lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor,
      facilisis luctus, metus</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="testimonialBox">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/100" />
  <div class="testimonialContent">
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
      Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus
      lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor,
      facilisis luctus, metus</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

width `display : flex;` , you can use `flex-flow`

*for older browsers: use the display:table & direction  method*

```css
/* alternate flow direction */

.testimonialBox:nth-child(even) {
  flex-flow: row-reverse
}


/* end alternate */

.testimonialBox {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 50px 0;
  border: 2px solid #c90;
  box-shadow: -5px 5px 20px #888888;
  min-height: 300px;
  display: flex;
}

.testimonialContent,
.testimonialBox>img {
  margin: auto 1em;
  ;
}
```

```html
<div class="testimonialBox">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/100" />
  <div class="testimonialContent">
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
      Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus
      lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor,
      facilisis luctus, metus</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="testimonialBox">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/100" />
  <div class="testimonialContent">
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
      Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus
      lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor,
      facilisis luctus, metus</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="testimonialBox">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/100" />
  <div class="testimonialContent">
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
      Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus
      lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor,
      facilisis luctus, metus</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Worked perfectly - THANK YOU!